# Ordered proximity search

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj, solandra

By ordered I mean term1 will always come before term2 in the document.

I have two documents:
1. "By ordered I mean term1 will always come before term2 in the document"
2. "By ordered I mean term2 will always come before term1 in the document"

if I make the query:

```
"term1 term2"~Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

my results is: 2 documents

How can I query to have one result (only if term1 come before term2):
"By ordered I mean term1 will always come before term2 in the document"

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use [SpanNearQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/SpanNearQuery.html)
This Matches spans which are near one another. One can specify slop, the maximum number of intervening unmatched positions, *as well as whether matches are required to be in-order*.

However, the dismax and edismax query parsers with Solr uses the phrase query and hence the match is always unordered.

[SurroundQueryParser](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SurroundQueryParser) supports the Span queries with an option to make a query for both ordered and unordered terms with a slight change in the syntax.
Although this Query Parser is available with the trunk only.

More info @ http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/02/22/exploring-query-parsers/

Answer (score 0):

Look up span query. http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/07/18/the-spanquery/